# Where can i find a complete android.jar for my android studio sdk?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, missing-features

While developing applications it's annoying to see thousands errors in sources (example: PackageManager uses the SystemApi annotation but its only in sources and not in android.jar (classes) )
Look: [image]

And this is my android.jar:
[image]

As you can see, the entire "com" folder is missing! But in the sources zip, its there.
So where can i find a complete android.jar?

Sorry for the low quality question i don't know an other way to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i found this website https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.rover12421.android.hide/framework/Q_10.0_29/source-code

From there i downloaded the hidden apis and its working perfectly.
i do not delete the question because someone else might have the same problem but find this